# Get-MailboxFolderStatistics out-file shows only numbers

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm using this script below to count the number of folders that certain mailboxes have. I am currently running into a problem. If I want to check 10 mailboxes and suppose that 1 mailbox has no folder at all, Powershell skips it in the export. So I only have 9 rows in my csv file and I can never know which mailbox was skipped. How can I ensure that the email address is also exported during this script?

```
$users = gc "c:\temp\user-list.txt"

foreach ($user in $users) { (Get-mailboxfolderstatistics -identity $user).Count | fl | out-file -FilePath C:\emails.csv -append}
```

**The user-list.txt file contains:**

- mailbox1@mycomp.com
- mailbox2@mycomp.com
- mailbox3@mycomp.com
- mailbox4@mycomp.com
- mailbox5@mycomp.com
- mailbox6@mycomp.com
- mailbox7@mycomp.com
- mailbox8@mycomp.com
- mailbox9@mycomp.com
- mailbox10@mycomp.com

**The export file emails.csv looks like this:**

- 50
- 36
- 35
- 35
- 36
- 36
- 36
- 49
- 36

Comment: Well, you asked it for the `.Count`, what did you expect other than numbers? :)

Comment: Yes I know :) But I did not know powershell skips the mailbox that contains nothing so what I was going to do is paste the emails in front of the export :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of outputting the count alone, create an object that has both the mailbox name and count attached, then use `Export-Csv` to create the CSV file:

```
$users |Select @{Name='Username';Expression={$_}},@{Name='FolderCount';Expression={@(Get-mailboxfolderstatistics -identity $_).Count}} |Export-Csv C:\emails.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi Mathias. Thank you for the comment but this does not work. Every mailbox gets the same folder count value of the first mailbox?

Comment: @ThijsDriesen My bad, forgot to replace `$user` with `$_` in the example. I've updated the answer now